# "XXX.foo is not a function" after browserify two files into bundle

Tags: javascript, npm, browserify

I use browserify to bundle two java script files into one with following command:

`browserify X1.js X2.js --standalone XXX > bundle.js`

X1.js contains following function:

```
function foo() {
   console.log("something")
}
```

And I'm exporting it that way:

```
module.exports = {foo: foo};
```

What I want to do is call that function inside my index.html like this:

```
XXX.foo()
```

And it seems like it recognizes "XXX" module, but not "foo" function. Why is that a case?

> Uncaught TypeError: XXX.foo is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the ' ' to the foo:

```
module.exports = {'foo': foo};
```

Then, you could call the foo function like you did:

```
XXX.foo();
```

Otherwise, you can do something like:

```
exports.foo = foo;
```

Comment: Neither option solves my issue, still getting exactly the same error. How should I import it inside index.html anyway? Is ```<script src="bundle.js"></script>``` the right way?

Comment: I think maybe you're using node.js module in html, it won't work. Try ES6 import and export statements

Comment: @ChrisKao absolutely, I think so !

Comment: @Mular8, something like this: import { foo } from './X1.js';

Comment: @ChrisKao @Ahmad MOUSSA but it was working like this when I was using just ```browserify X1.js --standalone XXX > bundle.js``` without second js file. I tried switching to ES6 but it only led to another problems.